# What are you guys having today? vs What are you having guys today?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence

> What are you guys having today?
>   or
>   What are you having guys today?

Can anyone tell me which of the above statements are correct and why?

Comment: They are questions, not statements. The second would need commas round _guys_ to make any sense at all.